# Use Assets to create transformations of external images

Tags: assets

Can I somehow use Asset transformations on external images (having them cached on my server)?

Let's say I have this image on "http://www.example-external-website.com/image.jpg" and I wan't to pull this image into my own server and create a small 100x100 thumbnail.

Is this possible?

Comment: Perfect! A little plugin magic will do the trick then. Thanks @BrandonKelly.